Unable to install CrewAI - Get a VSwhere error
While installing CrewAI using Pip install CrewAI , I was asked to install Vswhere.exe, which I did by installing MSBuild Tools with C++ however I still get this error while installing numpy. Wonder what else i am missing?
Build type: native build
Project name: NumPy
Project version: 1.26.4
WARNING: Failed to activate VS environment: Could not parse vswhere.exe output
Was expecting a clean install of numpy library to start build some agents. I am doing this install on a Windows11 laptop.
FUll Error output below
`Collecting numpy<2,>=1 (from langchain<0.2.0,>=0.1.0->crewAI)
Using cached numpy-1.26.4.tar.gz (15.8 MB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Installing backend dependencies ... done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
× Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [21 lines of output]
+ D:\Program Files\python\llama3_env\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\srira\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-nrzte6on\numpy_ccee6a9a4d144d588d06a6d02f9bf07e\vendored-meson\meson\meson.py setup C:\Users\srira\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-nrzte6on\numpy_ccee6a9a4d144d588d06a6d02f9bf07e C:\Users\srira\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-nrzte6on\numpy_ccee6a9a4d144d588d06a6d02f9bf07e.mesonpy-eygusz5h -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md --native-file=C:\Users\srira\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-nrzte6on\numpy_ccee6a9a4d144d588d06a6d02f9bf07e.mesonpy-eygusz5h\meson-python-native-file.ini
The Meson build system
Version: 1.2.99
Source dir: C:\Users\srira\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-nrzte6on\numpy_ccee6a9a4d144d588d06a6d02f9bf07e
Build dir: C:\Users\srira\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-nrzte6on\numpy_ccee6a9a4d144d588d06a6d02f9bf07e.mesonpy-eygusz5h
Build type: native build
Project name: NumPy
Project version: 1.26.4
WARNING: Failed to activate VS environment: Could not parse vswhere.exe output
  ..\meson.build:1:0: ERROR: Unknown compiler(s): [['icl'], ['cl'], ['cc'], ['gcc'], ['clang'], ['clang-cl'], ['pgcc']]
  The following exception(s) were encountered:
  Running `icl ""` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
  Running `cl /?` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
  Running `cc --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
  Running `gcc --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
  Running `clang --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
  Running `clang-cl /?` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
  Running `pgcc --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"

  A full log can be found at C:\Users\srira\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-nrzte6on\numpy_ccee6a9a4d144d588d06a6d02f9bf07e\.mesonpy-eygusz5h\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
  [end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed
× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.
note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.`

What is your Python version? is the location of vswhere on your PATH? did you try to install from VS code command line?

This was resolved by installing VIsual Studio tools build hit with other issues but this is not a concern anymore.

Resolved this error by installing Visual Studio build however main problem seems to be packaging issues not supported by Python 3.12 and 3.13. Original pip install for crew worked with python 3.11.
